# question about algebras and sigma algebras

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be an infinite set(countable or not) and put
$$ \mathscr{A} = \{ A \in 2^{\Omega} : A \; \text{is finite or} \; A^c \; \text{is finite} \} $$
$\mathscr{A}$ is an algebra, but not a sigma algebra.

$Attempt$:

$\varnothing $ is trivially finite, so $\varnothing \in \mathscr{A}$.

Since $\Omega^c = \varnothing$ which is finite. Hence, $\Omega \in \mathscr{A}$.

If $A \in \mathscr{A}$, then trivially $A^c \in \mathscr{A} $

Let $A_1,...,A_n \in \mathscr{ A} $. If they are all finite, then $\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i $ is also finite and hence $\bigcup_i A_i \in \mathscr{ A} $.

If $A_1^c,...,A_n^c $ are finite, then

$$ \mathscr{A} \ni\bigcup A_i^c = ( \bigcap A_i)^c \implies \bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i \in \mathscr{A}$$

So $\mathscr{A}$ is an algebra. Is this a correct solution?? Moreover, I am kind of stuck trying to find the counterexample  so that $\mathscr{A}$ is not a sigma algebra. Any help would be greatly appreaciated.

### Improved solution:

Obviously $\Omega, \varnothing \in \mathscr{A}$. If $A \in \mathscr{A}$, then trivially $A^c \in \mathscr{A} $. Next, suppose $A_1,...,A_n \in \mathscr{A} $. If $A_i$ is finite for all $i$, then $\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i $ is also finite and so it belongs to $\mathscr{A} $. If not all of the $A_i's$ are finite, then at least one of them, say $A_k$ has finite complement. Since $A_k \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i $, we have that $(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i )^c \subset A_k^c $ and so $(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i )^c \in \mathscr{A} $ which implies that $\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i \in \mathscr{A} $. Finally, since $(\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i)^c = \bigcup_i A_i^c \in \mathscr{A} $, we see that $\mathscr{A}$ is indeed an algebra. However, if we let $A_n = \{ n \} $ (as subsets of $\Omega = \mathbb{R}$) for all $n=1,2....$ then $A_n \in \mathscr{A}$ but $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \notin \mathscr{A}$. It follows that $\mathscr{A} $ is not a $\sigma-$algebra.

Comment: You also need to do unions like $A \cup B$ where $A$ is finite and $B^c$ is finite.

Comment: The de Morgan argument uses $(\cap_{i=1}^n A_i)^c = \cup_{i=1}^n A_i^c$, as it stands the equation is incorrect. The counterexample fails, as the union is $\mathbb{N}$ which *is* in $\mathscr{A}$ having a finite (i.e. empty) complement. Make sure that the complement of the union is not finite.

Comment: Should be better now. But, isnt $\mathbb{N}$ infinite ?

Comment: @Henno Brandsma : But, we are given $\Omega $ is infinite. We can take $\Omega = \mathbb{R} $ and so $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{N}$ is infinite.

Comment: If you're in the reals, it's OK. This wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When all $A_i$ are finite, the argument works. But what if this is not the case?

When this is *not* the case we only know that at least one $A_i$ has finite complement. But then the complement of $\cup_i A_i$ is even smaller, so also finite. Hence in that case the finite union is also in $\mathscr{A}$.

The finite intersections need not be checked separately, this follows from de Morgan and being closed under finite unions and complements.

The proof breaks down only when we take countably many finite sets: the union is no longer finite in general, and need not be coifing as well. Make an example in the natural numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have improved my solution with your suggestion. Would you mind giving me feedback this time? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the proof seems correct :)

a counterexample: consider $\mathbb{N}$, and let $A_n=\{2n\}$. then every $A_n$ is in the algebra, but their union, $\bigcup A_n=\{2n:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is not in the algebra.

Comment: The proof is not correct as it stands: only one case for finite union is shown, and also only one case for finite intersections....

Comment: no, he showed all cases for union. you don't need to show it for intersection.

Comment: Read the proof: if all $A_i$ are finite then the *union* is in the algebra. if all complements of $A_i$ are finite, then their *intersection* is in the algebra. But this does not cover all possibilities for the $A_i$.

Comment: yes, so that need to be changed :)